# Force unlock a sqlite database on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Now I know the real answer here is find where the missing finalize statement is , ensure it is closed on all routes through the delegate.
However I do have a situation on a real app that around 1 in 50,000 people occasionally get the app into a state where the database is locked.
I am searching for the code path that causes it but have yet to find a way to reproduce, so would like in the next update to at least have an error recovery system.

I know when the app starts the database should not be locked , so can test for that error condition - but when in that situation how can I force it all to unlock ?

Comment: I know of no way to force it to unlock (except maybe close the db and reopen, but I don't know if you can even do that if the database is locked), but the right solution is to prevent locking in the first place. The only way that I know of to have the database be locked is if you're doing concurrent operations. Or if you're opening a database, using it, not closing it, but trying to open it again. Might either of those be possible in your app? The solution will vary depending upon which applies. But a failure to finalize only causes leaks, as I understand it, not locks.

Comment: I did some tests and a failure to finalize did manage to cause a lock , but I had to hack that in. As the database remains locked even after a reboot of the device I am very confused.

Comment: That's fascinating because I'm trying to reproduce these symptoms by commenting out `sqlite3_finalize` calls (for both `SELECT`, `INSERT`, and `UPDATE` queries), not calling `sqlite3_close`, throwing an exceptions, etc., and I can't. I believe you, but there must be some weird convergence of other issues because generally failing to call `sqlite3_finalize` generally doesn't cause this problem. At least you demonstrated empirically that calling `sqlite3_finalize` will fix the problem, so it's easy enough to make sure your app does that. But very weird.

Comment: I had to run 1000's of database operations in a loop to cause it, my theory was then to figure out a way to unlock and locked database. So far I failed.

Comment: Is the problem that your database is now permanently locked? If so, I'd try opening it in the Mac OS `sqlite3` program, perhaps `VACUUM` the database, and see if that fixes it. Or is the problem that your app is periodically failing to `sqlite3_finalize`, which is causing a temporary problem. If so, you obviously just need to figure out why you app is doing that and remediate that.

Comment: Once the problem occurs in the app , the database remains permanently locked. I can't be sure it is a lack of finalize , it is just a method I have used to try and force the issue.

Comment: And have you tried `sqlite3_exec` of the `vacuum`? But, regardless, it feels like we're trying to cure the symptom rather than the disease. It seems like you have to figure out how your database is getting locked. (And are we _sure_ it's "locked" and not otherwise corrupted (e.g. app crashed while db was open)?)

Comment: Still not managed to find it :-( , but I added a vacuum to my detect and recover code and I haven't had any customer emails. I am beginning to think it is a crash or external event causing it rather than anything specific to my code base and am trying to setup some automated testing around those theorys